# Prove that the language $L_1 = \{a^ib^{2i}c^j \;|\; i,j ≥ 0\}$ is context-free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Prove that the language $L_1 = \{a^ib^{2i}c^j \;|\; i,j ≥ 0\}$ is context-free.

I have a grammar like this but there are some strings that are not be able to be generated

$$\begin{align}
S &\to aSbb \;|\; C \\
C &\to cC \;|\; \epsilon
\end{align}$$

One example is the string $abbc$ cannot be generated.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it. Consider that $L_1$ is simply the concatenation of $L_a$ and $L_c$, where $L_a = \{a^ib^{2i} \;|\; i ≥ 0\}$ and $L_c = \{c^j \;|\; j ≥ 0\}$, since the two parts of each sentence are independent of each other.

That should suggest a grammar which starts with the production $L\to AC$, and which then proceeds to define $A$ and $C$ in the obvious way.

Comment: L -> AC
A -> aAbb | ϵ
C -> cC | ϵ

Comment: Does that seem right? :)

Comment: @Matthew: You now have to prove that it generates the correct language, so you should acquire more confidence as you do the proof :)

Comment: I thought that since we can show that it has a CFG, then it is a context free language. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, if the language has a CFG, then it is a context-free language. You have to prove that the CFG actually generates exactly the target language. (Or, at least, that's what I would expect if I'd asked the question.) Such proofs are not difficult, and they count for a lot more than "Some guy on the internet said this was the right CFG".

Comment: That makes sense. I'm just not sure how to go about it. I am taking this course at the university level. How would I go about such a proof? I would have to show that the grammar generates every possible string in the language wouldn't I?

Comment: @Matthew: Yes. You have to show that any string in the language has a derivation from the grammar, and that every string derived from the grammar is in the language. (That is, two separate proofs.) Showing the derivation is trivial, and the other way is almost as simple. Once you've done that, you no longer have to ask "Does that look right?" because you know that it is :) If in doubt, ask your professor or TA.